# Magmi import not saving msrp, not sure why?

Tags: magmi

I'm using Magmi to import products into my store and it is working absolutely brilliantly, except that the MSRP value is not getting saved for some reason. The file imports without any errors but when I go into the catalog manager and actually look at the product, the msrp value is 0.00 regardless of what value is in the file.  As far as I can tell, the column name should be "msrp", so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Can someone help me out? It's probably something totally obvious that I'm missing but I'm at a loss.  Thanks!

Here's the test CSV I'm uploading:

```
"store","websites","attribute_set","type","sku","category_ids","name","manufacturer","meta_title","meta_description","image","small_image","thumbnail","price","cost","msrp","weight","description","meta_keyword","short_description","status","tax_class_id","visibility"
"admin","base","SJ Products","simple","XCL-XN100","2556","Xcelite XN100 5 13/16 Inch Light Duty Precision Knife","Xcelite Tools","Xcelite XN100 5 13/16 Inch Light Duty Precision Knife","Xcelite XN100 5 13/16 Inch Light Duty Precision Knife -  Tools & Test Equipment, Knives & Replacement Blades - SJ Media Systems","/XCL-XN100.JPG","/XCL-XN100.JPG","/XCL-XN100.JPG","2.6","2.23","$2.60",".04","<strong>Features:</strong><ul><li>Designed for light-duty cutting on paper </li><li>Also for soft and light-weight materials or wood </li><li>Replacement blade: XNB103 </li></ul>","Tools & Test Equipment,Knives & Replacement Blades","On Backorder","1","Taxable Goods","4"
```

Answer (score 3):

remove the $ before msrp value it should work much better.

Comment: Perfect, that's what it was!  I knew it was something obvious that I was missing.  Thanks for the help!